# mm/dd hh:mm:ss to float

Tags: matlab, time, octave

I have some data that I'm parsing in a set of files.
The files contain the year, month, day, hour, minute, and seconds demarcations for a number of data points.

Here is an example of the stream:

```
> 2010/01/01,00:00:00.979131, 27.4485,  51.9362, 14.8,  6
> 2010/01/01,00:00:01.021977, 27.5149,  51.9375, 16.0,  6
> 2010/01/01,00:00:01.074032, 27.4797,  51.9446, 14.5, 10
> 2010/01/01,00:00:01.663689, 25.8441,-152.8141, 14.6,  6
```

So far, I can do this to obtain seconds:

```
raw = textscan(fid, '%d/%d/%d %d:%d:%f %f %f %f %d', 'delimiter', ',');
m = cellfun(@double, raw, 'UniformOutput', false); %convert to doubles
seconds = ((m{:,4} *  3600.0) + (m{:,5} * 60.0) + m{:,6});
```

Discarding the year, how can I use what I have, plus some special magic involving the month and day to create a monotonically increasing number that represents days in the year as a float?

Comment: Why do you discard the year? Is it that the data is always for only one year? If there is several years involved, then should ie `01.01.2012` and `01.01.2013` (same month and day but different year) result in the same float value? Oh, and are you looking for a general algorithm or do you want to know how to implement it in octave/matlab?

Comment: @ain yes, the data is always for one year.

Comment: @ain if you have a general algorithm, this would also help me immensely.  thanks!

Comment: I were going to recommend something that would have worked like `datenum()` but it now looks like you do have requirement that the value must be in the 0..1 range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`datenum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) , for example:

```
 datenum(Y, M, D, H, MN, S)
```

returns the serial date numbers for corresponding elements of the Y, M, D, H, MN, and S (year, month, day, hour, minute, and second) array values. datenum does not accept milliseconds in a separate input, but as a fractional part of the seconds (DateString) input. Inputs Y, M, D, H, MN, and S must be arrays of the same size (or any can be a scalar) of type double. You can also specify the input arguments as a date vector, [Y M D H MN S].

Comment: How can I subtract/do math regarding the Y portion of the value so that I get a float from 0-1?  Do I simply subtract 734139?

Comment: Why do you need a float between 0-1 ? what exactly do you want to do? You can normalize any vector `v` between 0 and 1 useing: `vn=(v-min(v))./(max(v)-min(v))`

Comment: Thanks.  I want to represent the date as a stream of values throughout the year from the beginning (0) to the end (1).